# Finding $7$ inverse modulo $11$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, congruences

I'm trying to find the inverse of $7$ modulo $11$. From what I understand, the steps are:

\begin{align}
&11 = 1(7) + 3 \\
&7 = 2(3) + 1 \\
\end{align}

From here, you work backwards

\begin{align}
1 &= 7 - 2(3) \\
&= 7 - 2(11-7) \\
&= 7 - 2(11) + 2(7) \\
&= -2(11) + 3(7)
\end{align}

Now, here I see that $7$'s inverse modulo is $3$ but there can be many more (right?). The answer book says that one of them is $8$. Now, assuming my previous steps are correct; how do I find the others?

Thanks!

EDIT:

\begin{align}
11 &= 1(7) + 4 \\
7 &= 1(4) + 3 \\
4 &= 3(1) + 1
\end{align}

Then,

\begin{align}
1 &= 4 - 1(3) \\
&= 4 - 1(7 - 4) \\
&= 4 - 7 + 4 \\
&= -7 + 2(4) \\
&= -7 + 2(11 - 7)\\
&= -7 + 2(11) - 2(7) \\
&= 2(11) - 3(7)
\end{align}

Comment: Isn't it $11 = 1(7) + 4$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, the ring of integers modulo $p$ is in fact always a field, so $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ is a field. This means the multiplicative inverse of $7 \pmod{11}$ is unique.

Comment: @2012ssohn Very good point.. :/ (Revision in process.. `:)`)

Comment: I have updated my answer, is my revision correct?

Comment: Since the numbers are small enough you can test out values. You want to find a value of $x$ satisfying: $7x = 11k + 1$. Just test out vales of $k$. $k = 5$ gives a solution of $x = 8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, I have figured out how they arrived at $8$. My first mistake was the incorrect euclidean algorithm execution. So, below is the correct one:

\begin{align}
11 &= 1(7) + 4 \\
7 &= 1(4) + 3 \\
4 &= 3(1) + 1
\end{align}

Then we work backwards

\begin{align}
1 &= 4 - 1(3) \\
&= 4 - 1(7 - 4) \\
&= 4 - 7 + 4 \\
&= -7 + 2(4) \\
&= -7 + 2(11 - 7)\\
&= -7 + 2(11) - 2(7) \\
&= 2(11) - 3(7)
\end{align}

From here, we can use the following:

\begin{align}
x &= x_0 + jb \quad\quad j \in \mathbb{Z} \\
y &= y_0 + ka \quad\quad k \in \mathbb{Z} \\
\end{align}

In this case, we have $x = -3 + 11j$ and $y = 2 + 7k$.  Ignoring $y$, we can yield $8$ with $j=1$.

Comment: You already have it without the "From here..." thing: $$7\cdot(-3)+2\cdot11=1\implies 7\cdot(-3)=1\pmod {11}\implies 7^{-1}=-3$$and since $\;8+3=0\pmod{11}$, we finally get that $\;7^{-1}=-3=8\pmod{11}$ +1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ 11\!:\ 7\equiv -\color{#c00}4,\,$ and $\ {\rm mod}\ 2n\!-\!1\!:\ 2n\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, 4n^2\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}4^{-1}\equiv n^2$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Fermat's theorem to find the modular inverse.
$$a^p \equiv a \mod p$$
Multiply $a^{-2}$ on both sides:
$$\implies a^{p-2} \equiv a^{-1} \mod p$$

Hence, $a$ inverse modulo $p$ is $a^{p-2} \mod p$

In your case,

$7^9 \mod 11 \equiv 49^4*7 \equiv 5^4*7 \equiv 9*7 \equiv 8$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: $7x \equiv 1 \equiv 56 \;\; \text{mod} \; 11$ and $\gcd(7,11)=1.$

Answer (score -1):

$8 \times 7 = 56$

$56 \ \mbox{mod $7$} = 1$

Done.

$7^{-1} \ \mbox{mod $11$} = 8$

Comment: Where did you get $8$?

Comment: @gekkostate,well,11 is so small that it is easy to find a multiple that is 1 more than a multiple of 7.